# How to workaround Chrome's secure origin requirement for WebRTC

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc

Chrome has finally started blocking WebRTC (and likely some other "powerful features", as [described here](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/prefer-secure-origins-for-powerful-new-features)). Previously this was a preference that would get a message logged to the console, but now it's an outright block.

Obviously we could create a self signed certificate and actually set up HTTPS as we're supposed to, but this seems like a lot of work for a development environment. Chrome normally allowed `localhost` and variants, however, it's necessary to sometimes test across other computers, so that's insufficient.

So how do I disable this feature in Chrome?

Comment: Do you mean chrome is not allowing ```getUserMedia``` ?

Comment: https://webrtchacks.com/chrome-secure-origin-https/